# Print users coordinates when a button i pressed - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, coordinates

how do I print users location when i press the "Share" button? Here is my code

As you can see I have a line/code thats prints out the coordinates, but if I want those coordinates print out when I press the share button instead. Can I do that and if, how?

Hope you understand what I mean.

I'm pretty new in Xcode and Swift!

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Firebase

class MapController:  UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?
var mapView: MKMapView?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

let distanceSpan: Double = 500

var locationData: CLLocation!

let coordLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,100,400,50))


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(share))


    navigationItem.title = "Current Location"

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.mapView = MKMapView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, (self.window?.frame.width)!, (self.window?.frame.height)!))
    self.view.addSubview(self.mapView!)

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView!.showsUserLocation = true


    //Show User Location Button
    let button: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "MyLocationButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(locationManagerButton), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    // user is not logged in
    if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
        performSelector(#selector(handleLogout), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 0)



 }

    view.addSubview(coordLabel)

}

func share() {

    coordLabel.text = String(locationData.coordinate.longitude) + ", " +   String(locationData.coordinate.latitude)

}


func handleLogout() {

    do {
        try FIRAuth.auth()?.signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError)
    }

    let loginController = LoginController()
    presentViewController(loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}




func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
    if let mapView = self.mapView {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, self.distanceSpan, self.distanceSpan)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let locationData = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationData!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: locationData!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    self.mapView!.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")




}

func locationManagerButton() {

    mapView!.setCenterCoordinate(mapView!.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)



}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
{
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a label that contains the outputted coordinates.

```
coordLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,100,400,50))
view.addSubview(coordLabel);
```

then you will need a global coordinate variable that gets updated on the delegated call. So, after `let distanceSpan: Double = 500` put

```
var locationData: CLLocation!;
```

Then update the global value with in the delegate method...so instead of`location = locations.last` put `locationData = locations.last` and update the variable name elsewhere if needed.

Finally, output location data when needed.

```
func share(){
    coordLabel.text = String(locationData.coordinates.longitude) + ", " +   String(locationData.coordinates.latitude)
}
```

This is at first glance...you may run into some problems...keep me posted.

Comment: Okay, now i get this error when I press the button, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"  And EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0) on the coordLabel.text line

Comment: ok made an update. Sorry, wrote this of the top my head without testing, may be a few errors. Put 'let' by the coordLabel declaration

Comment: In the coordLabel.text = String(locationData.coordinates.longitude) + ", " +   String(locationData.coordinates.latitude)

Comment: also, make sure the line is near top of ViewDidLoad with the other UI setups

Comment: If I put let coordLabel.text = String(l.... do I get this error: Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: Sorry! wasnt thinking meant on the declaration, so: let coordLabel = UILabel(f......etc

Comment: yea that would have made no sense at all.

Comment: remove let from coordLabel.text that doesnt make sense (my bad)

Comment: Okay, now do I get the error that I wrote in the first comment

Comment: make sure all your changes are added to your original post so I can have a look. hold on.

Comment: change view.addSubview...etc to self.view...etc

Comment: Okay. Sorry - its always difficult getting it perfect without testing it myself. remove that ? and ill take another look.

Comment: Ok, got it. It must be because the annoying error message  (which doesnt tell you which value is hold the problem) is actually talking about the locationData value, not CoordLabel. try coordLabel.text = String(locationData?.coordinate.longitude) + ", " +   String(locationData?.coordinate.latitude)

Comment: okay, now dosen´t it appear any kind of error. But it shows nil, nil on the screen

Comment: that would only be because locationData is not set, because the delegated method was not yet called, set some break points.

Comment: just noticed you have: let locationData = ...etc in the didUpdateLocations. Get rid of 'let', as the whole point is that this locationData is defined earlier globally, so that we can change it and the change is accessible everywhere.